# How to transfer lines from a .txt file into an array

Tags: qt, plot

Hey guys I need to make an application using Qt that reads integers from a text file and creates a 2d plot from it. I figure that I need to transfer the integers from the txt file to an array but I am not sure how to do so.
The file has each integer on its own line. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well reading a file line by line and put the contents into a vector shouldn't be that hard. Have a look at the [QFile api docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html). They have some basic examples there.

```
std::vector<int> here_are_your_ints;
QFile file("yourFileWithIntegers.txt");
// basic error checking
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;
// read the contents line by line
while (!file.atEnd()) {
    QByteArray line = file.readLine();
    QDataStream ds(line);
    int int_in_line = 0;
    ds >> int_in_line;
    here_are_your_ints.push_back(int_in_line);
}
```

Searching for a good plotting library? I am using [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/).